# Почему в private static readonly не видно переменную из .env

Tags: node.js, typescript

Никак не могу разобраться почему так происходит. В коде закоментированны результаты вывода. Почему через `this` я получаю `undefined`

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

class Jwt{
  private static readonly secretAccess = process.env.ACCESS_SECRET;

  static generateToken(user_info:object){
    console.log(this.secretAccess);//undefined
    console.log(process.env.ACCESS_SECRET);//secret
    return(true);
  }

}

export default Jwt;
```

Comment: статическое же поле. Вместо `this.secretAccess` надо `Jwt.secretAccess`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov в ts и так, и так норм )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin подозреваю, что топикстартер сделал `new Jwt()`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov нет. использую так `let jwtToken = Jwt.generateToken(values)`

Comment: Тогда получается, что ваш Jwt со всеми своими статическими полями инициализируется до инициализации process.env

Comment: @AlexanderChernin не подскажите как это исправить ?

Comment: @zxcqwe `private static get secretAccess() { return process.env.ACCESS_SECRET;}`